# When does driver.get() complete?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

When using the `InternetExplorerDriver` (IE9 Win7) the `driver.get()` method blocks for some sites I'm testing. The site seems to be completely loaded, as the page is no longer **refreshing**, but the code just gets stuck at the `driver.get()` call. (this doesn't happen with the same site for the `FirefoxDriver`).

Anyone know any reason why this would happen or how best to troubleshoot it?

In particular the `WebDriver` api states

> "the method will block until the load is complete".

How is **"load is complete"** defined?

Comment: what version of Selenium are you using ? Latest release is 2.44. Similar issues here https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6955

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6190

Comment: I've tried it with Selenium 2.40 and 2.44.

Comment: Can u try with pageLoadTimeout?

Comment: Thanks for those links. Looks like it's an existing issue. I did try pageLoadTimeout() and it throws, as expected, a TimeoutException after the specified time.

Comment: @badhaircut - great then. By catching the exception - you can manage at least for the time being.   But it could still be an issue if your application itself is very slow!!